# page is jumping even after putting event.preventDefault();

Tags: jquery

So I've read about how to prevent page jumping with event.PreventDefault() and return false in jquery, but for some reason whenever i click on the link, the page still jumps up :\

I'm using the ClickSpark library to show animations whenever the user clicks, and I don't think it is causing the page to jump, but i might be wrong. i simply want the page to not jump up whenver a link is clicked.

What is interesting is that once the initial click that leads to a page jump to the top is done, the subsequent clicks do NOT lead to a page jump. I'm not sure why this is, would appreciate any comments as to why that is.

here's my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

var current_answer = $(this);
var question_id = '<%= mcq.id %>';
var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>";

  if (current_answer.text() === $(".correct-choice").text()) {
    clickSpark.setParticleImagePath('../../correct-answer-checkmark.png');
    clickSpark.setParticleCount(50);
    clickSpark.setParticleSize(20);
    clickSpark.setParticleSpeed(12);
    clickSpark.fireParticles($(this));
    $(".slider").fadeIn("750");

    current_answer.css({
        backgroundColor: '#78e08f',
        transition: ".25s all",
    });

    $("a.answer").not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).css({
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          transition: ".25s all"
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    current_answer.css({
        backgroundColor: '#e55039',
        transition: ".25s all"
    });
  }

$.ajax({
url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()},
success: function(response){
$("#display_result").text(response["result"]);
}
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

html

```
  <% mcq.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <%= link_to answer, "javascript:void(0);", class: "answer" %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

actual html output by rails:

```
 <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <a class="answer" href="javascript:void(0);">Yes</a>
    </div>

    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <a class="answer" href="javascript:void(0);">Maybe</a>
    </div>

    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <a class="answer" href="javascript:void(0);">No</a>
    </div>

    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <a class="answer" href="javascript:void(0);">Possibly</a>
    </div>

    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <a class="answer" href="javascript:void(0);">Perhaps</a>
    </div>
```

console.log

```
jQuery.fn.init(5)
0: a.answer
1: a.answer
2: a.answer
3: a.answer
4: a.answer
context: document
length: 5
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init [document, context: document]
selector: "a.answer"
__proto__: Object(0)
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/va76mu2y/

Comment: Hi @mazing. Please use `<button>` instead of `<a>`. It will do the job better, you don't have to prevent default behaviour :)

Comment: @DamianDziaduch unfortunately i can't change it, is there no other way?

Comment: show us your html code for <a class='answer'>. did you put href="#" ?

Comment: ```<% mcq.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <%= link_to answer, "javascript:void(0);", class: "answer" %>
    </div>

  <% end %>```

Comment: updated @RaymondTey

Comment: At the end of your event handler add this: return false;

Comment: @PoulBak that doesn't work! :\

Comment: @mazing try replacing `javascript:void(0);` with `#` or even better, `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @DamianDziaduch that does not work either :(

Comment: @mazing can you show us the html markup for `<a>` rendered by browser?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch i updated my post, thank you.

Comment: @mazing do you have any console error ?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch there is no error in the console :\

Comment: @mazing can you put `console.log($("a.answer"));` right after `$(document).ready(...`? Maybe your does not find any anchor

Comment: @DamianDziaduch i updated my post with the contents of console.log

Comment: @mazing so you script seems to be working as expected. Maybe page jump is caused by something else. You can add `console.log()` or `alert()` into you handler to verify that it is working as expected...